# How do you use Objective-C starting from the "Java JNI Application" template in XCode?

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, macos, java-native-interface

I want to use the NSStatusBar object from my Java application using JNI. I know there's some existing libraries out there but I've tried them and they don't have the correct drop down menu.

I'm starting from the "Java JNI Application" template in XCode and I simply put

```
NSString *str=@"";
```

to see if it could compile but this produces compilation errors when no other changes are made.

I assume I need to change some settings in the project configuration or add some header files to get this to work.

What needs to be done to allow me to use Objective-C/Cocoa starting from the "Java JNI Application" template?

(I'm assuming this tempalte is the best place to start but let me know if I'm wrong).
Thanks.

OSX10.5.8
XCode3.1.3

Comment: In the end I found I didn't want to use the template. I just made an "Empty Project" and built the jnilibs from a shell script. The main reason I ditched the JNI template is I couldn't figure out how change the package of the main JNI class in XCode. Also, I wanted the Java code to live with the rest of my java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add Foundation to your imports, and rename the file from .c to .m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```